# new NotificationCompat.Builder(Context) - how to setLargeIcon() from url

Tags: android, notifications

Am trying to `.setLargeIcon(getBitmapFromUrl(url)` and it is not setting.

```
    public void showSmallNotification(String title, String message, String url, Intent intent) {
    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(mCtx,ID_SMALL_NOTIFICATION,intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mCtx);

    Notification notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo_small).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo_small)
            .setLargeIcon(getBitmapFromURL(url))
            .setContentText(message)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .build();

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mCtx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(ID_SMALL_NOTIFICATION, notification);
}
```

here is where I convert the image from the url to bitmap

```
//The method will return Bitmap from an image URL
private Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String strURL) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strURL);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

Basically if I could glide the image. Fantastic.
anyways, a little help so my notifier will be simple and cool like twitter and instagram.
Thanks..

```
UPDATED: .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mCtx.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_logo_small)) works but url doesn't.
```

but the image i want to set is online (mysql)

Comment: I think you should use the local image, don't should use from URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you use Glide, you can download like this

```
GlideApp.with(this).asBitmap().skipMemoryCache(true).load(url).into(150, 150).get()
```

and you must set the notification after the image is downloaded,

Answer (score 0):

You should download the image before calling `setLargeIcon`

You can download image using AsyncTask:

```
public class DownloadImageAndShowNotification extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    private Context mContext;
    private String mUrl;

    DownloadImageAndShowNotification(Context context, String url) {
        super();
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mUrl = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        InputStream in;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(mUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            in = connection.getInputStream();
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Build your notification with the bitmap
    }
}
```